# Ubuntu 16.04 Running a jar does not take vpn IP

Tags: vpn, ip, jar

I am trying to run a jar on my ubuntu system and I am on vpn, instead of taking the host as my IP on VPN, it takes the localhost IP, ie. 127.0.0.1. It is a kind of listener and I need to run the jar on the vpn IP so that I can listen to events.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This can not be solved without knowing the content of that jar.

Comment: It is a maven project that exposes some REST endopoints, these endpoints  listen to events